# Parse source CSV and keep double quotes existing in some cases

Tags: spring-boot, csv, parsing

I have following csvline as example in my sourcefile:

```
5002;Bankname ;ATM;Bank;;Bank Subname;Street No. 62;48732678;ExampleCity;250000628;Examplename;00001070;6011;"1,00";"20,00";MC;"";"0,42";R;Inter;"";"";"";09/2022
```

As you can see there are some columns with double quotes. Since the customer wants to keep the exact format, i want to read this csv as it is and keep all the double quotes if there exist any. So, the output should look exactly the same.

Is there any proper soultion to implement this using SpringBoot?

Comment: just read line by line and split each line after ; separator into a list and the double quote are keept as they are.